# How to make ajax call to get the data from url using backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I am new to backbone js and i wanted to call one external url and i want the which will fetch from the url output.

**I have tried like the following**

```
var MyApp.myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://senthil_c/DSCFrameWork/UVIndevSvc.svc/GetWeatherByZipcode/02111/json'
});

var MyApp.myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind("change",this.render,this);
        this.model.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        alert('do awesome stuff here');
    }
});
```

I dont know how to call and i dont know this one is correct or not any one suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model = new MyApp.myModel();
    this.model.fetch();
}
```

Comment: the link will have the json value but i cant get it

Comment: are you running your application on webserver? and server that hosting this json file and your server are same? browsers by default doesn't allow cross domain calls